# Java - How to Test Catch Block?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, try-catch, catch-block

Bit of a repost, but a certain catch-22 about not having enough reputation means I can't comment on any of the duplicate threads! (cough cough)

I'm trying to test the catch block of a try-catch using Mockito; is it possible to make a mock throw an exception that is handled by the method being tested? I can't use doThrow()...when()... or @Test(expected = Foo.class) because the exception is handled. I want to test that the method handles Exceptions properly.

```
@Controller
public class StockExchangeController {

    public ModelAndView placeOrder(ModelAndView mav, MyObj myObj) {

        try {
            validator.validate(myObj); // Throws CustomException if validation fails
            mav.setViewName("successPage");

        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            mav.setViewName("failPage");
        }

        return mav;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to stub the behaviour of my "validatorObject", like

```
doThrow(new CustomException()).when(validatorMock).validate();
```

Is there a way to do this?

The answer [here (Test catch block logic with Junit and mockito)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569595/test-catch-block-logic-with-junit-and-mockito) doesn't work (I believe) because the exception is handled before it gets to test level.

Tips and thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the `validator` come from? Is it a member in the `StockExchangeController `? If so, where is it intialized?

Comment: `validator` actually comes from an @Autowried ValidatorFactory class that gets the appropriate validator - basically new MyObjValidator() instantiated in the Factory.

Answer (score 1):

[BDD](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/gwt.html) Style Solution

*Mockito* alone is not the best solution for handling exceptions, use *Mockito* with *Catch-Exception*

Mockito + [Catch-Exception](https://github.com/Codearte/catch-exception) + [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core)

```
given(otherServiceMock.bar()).willThrow(new MyException());

when(myService).foo();

then(caughtException()).isInstanceOf(MyException.class);
```

Sample code

- [Mockito + Catch-Exception + Assertj full sample](https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/7489190)

Dependencies

- eu.codearte.catch-exception:catch-exception:1.3.3
- org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0

Disadvantage

- Only Mockito up to 1.10.8 is supported

Comment: Too much boldface.  OTOH I looked at your raw text and I'm disappointed that SO markdown doesn't handle minor heading better.

Comment: Easily fixed. Use `#` headings instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why should `doThrow(..).when(..)...` not work?

The `placeOrder` method catches the exception and returns a testable result:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestStockExchangeController {

    @Mock
    Validator validator;

    @Mock MyObj myObj;

    @Test
    public void testException() throws CustomException {
        StockExchangeController sec = new StockExchangeController(validator);
        doThrow(new CustomException()).when(validator).validate(myObj);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = sec.placeOrder(new ModelAndView(), myObj);
        assertEquals("failPage", modelAndView.getViewName());
    }
}
```

---

I've tested with these two files:

Main source code:

```
//src/main/java/StockExchangeController.java
public class StockExchangeController {

    private ValidationFactory factory;

    public ModelAndView placeOrder(ModelAndView mav, MyObj myObj) {
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator("S");
        try {
            validator.validate(myObj); // Throws CustomException if validation fails
            mav.setViewName("successPage");
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            mav.setViewName("failPage");
        }
        return mav;
    }
}

class CustomException extends Exception {}

interface ValidationFactory {
    Validator getValidator(String s);
}

class Validator {
    public void validate(MyObj myObj) throws CustomException {}
}

class ModelAndView {
    private String viewName;

    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }

    public String getViewName() {
        return viewName;
    }
}

class MyObj {}
```

Test source code:

```
//src/test/java/TestStockExchangeController.java
//various imports
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestStockExchangeController {

    @Mock
    private Validator validator;

    @Mock
    private ValidationFactory validationFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    StockExchangeController target = new StockExchangeController();

    @Test
    public void testException() throws CustomException {
        MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
        when(validationFactory.getValidator(anyString())).thenReturn(validator);
        doThrow(new CustomException()).when(validator).validate(myObj);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = target.placeOrder(new ModelAndView(), myObj);

        assertEquals("failPage", modelAndView.getViewName());
        verify(validator).validate(myObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it may be my poor understanding of Mock objects? My `validator` Mock is actually returned by a ValidationFactory which gets the appropriate Validator implentation:
`when(validationFactory.getValidator(any(TransactionForm.class))).thenReturn(ransactionValidatorMock);`
I then also add
`doThrow(new CustomException).when(transactionValidatorMock).validate();`, but `verify(transactionValidatorMock).validate();` gets zero interactions. Does my approach make sense?

Comment: @DannySalvadori The approach makes sense. Are you mocking the correct method? You write about mocking with `doThrow(new CustomException).when(transactionValidatorMock).validate();`, but the actual call is `validator.validate(myObj);`, which would require mocking with `doThrow(new CustomException).when(transactionValidatorMock).validate(myObj);`